# Arduino ,How I can see the value (0 or 5) on my screen, where I connected my sensors output to analog input A0,A1.. pins

Tags: serial, analogread

I am working in my project and I want to see the output of my sensors as (0 or 5).
The maximum read was 770 and the minimum read was 0. So, how can I see the  value (0 or 5) on my screen, where I connected my sensors output to analog input A0, A1 pins.
I did the following code, but it didn't work:

```c
void setup(){
Serial.begin(9600);   
}
void loop()
{
if (analogRead(0)<385)
      Serial.print("0");
 else
      Serial.print("5");
      Serial.print('  ');

if (analogRead(1)<385)
      Serial.print("0");
   else
      Serial.print("5");
      Serial.print('  ');

if (analogRead(2)<385)
      Serial.print("0");
  else
      Serial.print("5");
      Serial.print('  ');

if (analogRead(3)<385)
      Serial.print("0");
  else
      Serial.print("5");
      Serial.print('  ');

if (analogRead(4)<385)
      Serial.print("0");
  else
      Serial.print("5");
      Serial.print('  ');

if (analogRead(5)<385)
      Serial.print("0");
  else
      Serial.print("5");
      Serial.print('  ');

delay(1500); 
}
```

Note: I have 5 light sensors in my circuit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code - it should help you see what is going on more clearly:

```
const int threshold = 385;

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);   
}

void loop()
{
  int reading = analogRead(0);
  Serial.print("Analog 0 reads ");
  Serial.print(reading);
  Serial.print(" - this maps to ");
  if (reading < threshold){
    Serial.println("0");
  } else {
    Serial.println("5");
  }    

  reading = analogRead(1);
  Serial.print("Analog 1 reads ");
  Serial.print(reading);
  Serial.print(" - this maps to ");
  if (reading < threshold){
    Serial.println("0");
  } else {
    Serial.println("5");
  }    

  reading = analogRead(2);
  Serial.print("Analog 2 reads ");
  Serial.print(reading);
  Serial.print(" - this maps to ");
  if (reading < threshold){
    Serial.println("0");
  } else {
    Serial.println("5");
  }    

  reading = analogRead(3);
  Serial.print("Analog 3 reads ");
  Serial.print(reading);
  Serial.print(" - this maps to ");
  if (reading < threshold){
    Serial.println("0");
  } else {
    Serial.println("5");
  }    

  reading = analogRead(4);
  Serial.print("Analog 4 reads ");
  Serial.print(reading);
  Serial.print(" - this maps to ");
  if (reading < threshold){
    Serial.println("0");
  } else {
    Serial.println("5");
  }    

  reading = analogRead(5);
  Serial.print("Analog 5 reads ");
  Serial.print(reading);
  Serial.print(" - this maps to ");
  if (reading < threshold){
    Serial.println("0");
  } else {
    Serial.println("5");
  }                                

  Serial.println();

  delay(1500); 
}
```

Comment: thanx mr stefandz its working .

Comment: Excellent - please mark the question as answered in that case.

Comment: but if you can see this code for the same Purpose:
int a0=23;
int a1=24;
int a2=25;
int a3=26;
int a4=27;
void setup(){
Serial.begin(9600);  
pinMode(a0,INPUT);
pinMode(a1,INPUT);
pinMode(a2,INPUT);
pinMode(a3,INPUT);
pinMode(a4,INPUT);


}
void loop()
{
   Serial.println(a0);
   Serial.println(' , ');
   Serial.println(a1);
   Serial.println('  ');
   Serial.println(a2);
   Serial.println('  ');
   Serial.println(a3);
   Serial.println('  ');
   Serial.println(a4);
   Serial.println('  ');
   delay(1500); 
}

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to achieve there, but I can tell you that without an analogRead or digitalRead statement in there, you're not going to be reading anything other than the values of the variables you set at the top. If you have a new question, please ask it separately.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DigitaRead command instead of analogread. It will give result in only 1 or 0. Hopefully this will help you.

Comment: This will use the microprocessor's internal logic thresholds, not the programmable threshold the original poster requested.

Comment: I don't think that's what he requested. He approached like that in his coding. Why should i do all this coding when arduino has its own solution.

Comment: From his original question: "the maximum read was 770 and the minimum read was 0". He clearly doesn't have 0 - 5V inputs, and hence his approach is more robust and less prone to error.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has multiple issues.

```
if (analogRead(1)<385)
      Serial.print("0");
   else
      Serial.print("5");
      Serial.print('  ');
```

Note that `Serial.print('  ');` is not at all the same as `Serial.print("  ");`

---

Also, by the indentation it looks like you should be using braces. Amended code:

```
if (analogRead(1)<385)
      Serial.print("0");
   else
      {
      Serial.print("5");
      Serial.print("  ");
      }
```

Without the braces only the first statement after the *else* is conditionally executed.

If I am wrong about that, you should indent differently, eg.

```
if (analogRead(1)<385)
      Serial.print("0");
   else
      Serial.print("5");
Serial.print("  ");
```